# Can't start an activity in application onCreate

Tags: android

I am trying to start an activity after `n` seconds with a handler. The application was crashing on the `startActivity` call, so I put the handler code in my application's `onCreate`, and it is still crashing (which makes me think that the error comes from me not using `startActivity` well) :

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
            String roomName = this.getSettingValue(R.string.PREFERENCES_ROOM_NAME, "");
            Room room;
            try {
                room = this.getRoomWithName(roomName);
            } catch (ReservatorException ex) {
                    Toast err = Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    err.show();
                    return;
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(this, RoomActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("room", room);
            this.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Strange thing is that this work when called from a view, by using exactly the same code, but different context :

```
        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), RoomActivity.class);
        // ...
```

I am pretty new to Android ... so there may be information missing in that question, or I might even be trying to do something completely stupid who knows ?

**EDIT**

Link to the stacktrace : http://pastebin.com/vh2QC3xz

**EDIT2**

Here is the *handler* version of my code (so what I am trying to do in the end) :

```
public class ReservatorApplication extends Application {

private GoToFavouriteRoom goToFavouriteRoomRunable;
class GoToFavouriteRoom implements Runnable {

    ReservatorApplication app;

    public GoToFavouriteRoom(ReservatorApplication anApp){
        app = anApp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String roomName = app.getSettingValue(R.string.PREFERENCES_ROOM_NAME, "");
        Room room;
        try {
            room = app.getDataProxy().getRoomWithName(roomName);
        } catch (ReservatorException ex) {
            Toast err = Toast.makeText(app, ex.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            err.show();
            return;
        }
        RoomActivity.startWith(app, room);
    }

}

private final ReservatorAppHandler handler = new ReservatorAppHandler();
class ReservatorAppHandler extends Handler{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    String serverAddress = getSettingValue(R.string.PREFERENCES_SERVER_ADDRESS, "mail.futurice.com");// TODO: change to mail.futurice.com before delivery
    proxy = new SoapDataProxy(serverAddress);
    // proxy = new DummyDataProxy();
    proxy = new CachedDataProxy(proxy);
    addressBook  = new FumAddressBook();
    try {
        addressBook.prefetchEntries();
    } catch (ReservatorException e) {
        // TODO: DIE!
    }
    goToFavouriteRoomRunable = new GoToFavouriteRoom(this);
    handler.postDelayed(goToFavouriteRoomRunable, 20000);
}
```

Comment: Seems fine to me. But since you got a crash, you also got a stacktrace. Please post that, it's way easier to help you with it instead of guessing around.

Comment: Try removing all 'this' in the code...?

Comment: What does this class that is calling OnCreate extend from?

Comment: Oops, too late. The wild guess-party already started. :)

Comment: I feel kind of stupid even to have asked the question, because I don't have a clue of even how to approach a bug in Android :S, so it is so hard to explain ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ... I finally solved my problem, mainly thanks to @Drax

Apparently, you just can't start an activity from an application ... you need an instance of an activity. So :

```
public class ReservatorApplication extends Application { 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RoomActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Is just not valid, and causes a RunTimeException ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as crashing is concern when you start activity in handler with "this". it will take handler's context. and when you do getContext() it will take activity context.

Comment: But here the onCreate is the application, so `this` should be of the right type. When using the handler, I create a Runnable `myRunnable = new MyRunnable(this);`, this being the application, and therefore, the `run` method has access to the application since it's a member of the Runnable.

Comment: From the stack trace i found you have not called "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" so please try out this

Comment: What is "savedInstanceState" ?

Comment: in your code you overrides wrong onCreate. it should be @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState). it will solve the problem. savedInstanceState is the bundle of the activity has to start with when launched

Comment: Looks like eclipse is not of the same opinion `@Override public void onCreate()` no params seems to be the right method. Different version maybe ?

Comment: Eclipse will stop you for compile time error. so this will lead you to  run time which you have posted here :)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, eclipse doesn't compile with `@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` :(

Comment: You need to extend your class from Activity.

Comment: Ok ... you probably thought that this code was running in Activity.onCreate, but it is in Application.onCreate. On advice of a colleague I'll try to move it to the activity and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, RoomActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RoomActivity.class);
```

Comment: same pb ... it just crashes also :(

Answer (score 0):

It`s hard to answer without seeing the stack trace from logcat, but I found that sometimes you need to pass the application context to the a new Intent before starting an Activity.

Try this line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RoomActivity.class);
```